# latest Cygwin on Win10: smartmontools (smartctl etc) is in /usr/sbin - yet NO */sbin folders are in PATH

Tags: installation, path, windows-10, cygwin

Having used cygwin for a long time, I've just installed cygwin64 on a new Win10 laptop. (I placed the package collection in D:\Tech\Cygwin for whatever that's worth. Should NOT impact this AFAIK.)

Most everything seems fine... except:

- The default fresh-install path (or augmented path on installing packages?) does not include /sbin or /usr/sbin even though several packages install executables there (eg smartctl and more)

  - Specific example: install smartmontools.
  - smartctl.exe goes into /usr/sbin
  - yet $PATH doesn't include /usr/sbin
- "vi foo" gives an error: E1187: Failed to source defaults.vim

  - Again, vi is part of the default cygwin install
  - Yet, as of the current version, apparently not all needed default control / config files are placed properly. I haven't yet figured this one out.

In the past, I've never had first-install issues at all. Is manual configuration of various things like $PATH etc now expected for new users?

Comment: So what's the exact problem? After all, **you** set up the PATH, and if a directory is missing, just add it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You claim I setup the path? NO - installing cygwin presumably includes setting appropriate path for the context. I'll edit the question to make it more clear I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Seems nobody knows the answer. I did some more homework and learned:

1. It's apparently random whether installing a given package will verify and update the PATH to incorporate that package's (even default executable) folder.
2. By default, although several "base" category executables are in /sbin and /usr/sbin, those folders are NOT in $PATH.
3. No bug has been reported for this.
4. Here's my simplest workaround for the $PATH issue. If you want anything in /sbin or /usr/sbin to be on your $PATH, insert the following near the top of your ~/.bashrc

```
# Add sbin folders if not already in path
  if [ "${PATH/sbin}" == "${PATH}" ] ; then
    PATH=${PATH}:/sbin:/usr/sbin
    export PATH
    echo Added sbin to path
  fi
```

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate issues.

---

Missing `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` in `$PATH`:

The `smartmontools` developer has apparently decided that a privileged command such as `smartctl` belongs in `/usr/sbin`.

This seems in line with the [file system standard](https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/sbin.html), which says

> if a normal (not a system administrator) user will ever run it directly, then it must be placed in one of the "bin" directories.

For reasons I have yet to find out, Cygwin does not guarantee `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` to be in `$PATH` of the superuser. Such an adjustment seems to be left to the end-user for now. I'd do it as follows:

```
$ cygstart --action=runas env PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin smartctl ...
```

This opens a new terminal window with the privileges and environment of Administrator, but Cygwin environment as the normal user, with augmented PATH.

If interaction is needed

```
$ cygstart --action=runas env PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin bash -i
```

In the new privileged widow:

```
$ smartctl ...
```

or, use ssh as suggested [here](https://www.cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.su):

```
$ ssh -t $(id -nu)@localhost env PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin smartctl
```

This will work if the ssh service is enabled on the local machine,
allowing redirections of stdin, stdout, stderr.

---

Note that some systems merge `/bin` with `/usr/bin` and `/sbin` with `/usr/sbin`, as long as /usr/ is mounted early enough, or are on the same device, using symbolic links:

```
bin -> usr/bin
...
sbin -> usr/sbin
```

In recent Cygwin (as of today) all files are typically on the same device, and directories are mounted. Only one half of the merging is done, however:

- `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` differ
- `/usr/bin/` and `/bin` end up identical, as follows:

```
$ mount
C:/cygwin64/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin64/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin64 on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
...
$ cygpath -w /bin /usr/bin
C:\cygwin64\bin
C:\cygwin64\bin
```

Why this is so, I have yet to find out, too.

In the latter case, only one of `/usr/bin` or `/bin` would be sufficient in the `$PATH`, and the other redundant.

---

`E1187: Failed to source defaults.vim`:

Default cygwin installation includes `vim-minimal`, and apparently lacks the file `defaults.vim`. Installing package `vim-common` fixed this error.

This dislocation seems to have happened when splitting the package in upstream vim development. [Detail](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1969936) .